distinct counting open incident tickets at any give point in time
morning all,
struggling to come up with a solution to this one.
basically i need to be able to distinct count the No of tickets (ID)  open at any given time by date
i have a created date , an actual completion date and and incident_status (table has open and closed incidents in it.
can i do a fancy join to dates table that says date is between created and completion date?
so for every day of the year i need to be able to show how many incidents were open on that day
I do have a separate dates table Shown in example, but not sure how I would join this to the Incidents tables given what i am trying to do
Incidents and Dates Tables :

Totally unsure of how to handle this query

Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output as text not image so it can be easy for us to help .. Also include the query you have tried so far

Also, please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. From the screenshots I'm assuming it's SQL Server

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. and Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question are both applicable here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Fancy Join is 1=1 i.e. always true.
If incident is open then there won't be any value in ActualCompletionDate. I would be NULL, I hope.
select cal_date, count_of_open_tickets from (
select c.cal_date, count(distinct(i.id)) as count_of_open_tickets 
from (select ID, CreatedOn from dbo.Incident_All_2 where Incident_Status='Open') i 
inner join (select Date as cal_date from dbo.DATESDAYS where date<=current_timestamp()) c 
on 1=1 
where c.cal_date>=i.createdon 
group by c.cal_date ) calcultd_tbl
where cal_date='2024-05-17';

